# What's the react hooks equivalent of this setState?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-hooks

I found this code in the [`react-native-dynamic-search-bar`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-dynamic-search-bar), and I couldn't find a way to make it with [`react-native-hooks`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-hooks).

```js
this.setState({
  query: text,
  dataSource: newData,
});
```

And this is the whole function

```
  const filterProjectList = (text) => {
    var newData = dataBackup.filter((item) => {
      const itemData = item.name.toLowerCase();
      const textData = text.toLowerCase();
      return itemData.indexOf(textData) > -1;
    });
    this.setState({
      query: text,
      dataSource: newData,
    });
  };
```

Comment: [useState](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate)

Comment: does hooks knows that i'm changing those specifically?, because i got datasource above like this, const [dataSource, setDatasource] = useState();

Comment: i'm getting invariant violation: invalid hook call

Comment: you might be doing any one of the stated reasons for that https://reactjs.org/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use  [useState](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) hook instead of setState

and you can rewrite that like this :

```
  // yourComponent.js

    import React, {useState} from 'react'

   const yourComp =() =>{
    const [query,setQuery] = useState("")
    const [dataSource,setDatasource] = useState([])

    const filterProjectList = (text) => {
        var newData = dataBackup.filter((item) => {
          const itemData = item.name.toLowerCase();
          const textData = text.toLowerCase();
          return itemData.indexOf(textData) > -1;
        });
        setQuery(text)
        setDatasource(newData)

      };
     ....
     return <div>Hello World</div>
    }
```